# Show that $N_G(C)$ is just subgroup $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Consider the Galois extension of $K/L$ with $G:=Gal(K/L)$. Let $L\subset E \subset K$. Define $H:=\{\sigma\in G: \sigma(\alpha)=\alpha, \forall \alpha\in E\}$ with $H<G$. Let $C:=Gal(K/E)$. I am working on how to prove that
$$
N_G(C)=\{g\in G: gCg^{-1}=C\}
$$
is same as subgroup $H$.

---

What I am confused about currently is that using this theorem, we will get two different one-to-one correspondences by Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory:
$$
\{L \subset E \subset K\} \longleftrightarrow \{G > C>1\}
$$
and
$$
\{L \subset K^H \subset K\} \longleftrightarrow \{G > H>1\}
$$

To prove $H=N_G(C)$, I am stuck on both inclusion direction.

(1) For $h\in H$ and $c\in C$, we have for every $\alpha \in E$,
$$
hch^{-1}(\alpha)=hc(\alpha)
$$
but how to show that is just $c(\alpha)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish your argument for (1), since $c \in C = \operatorname{Gal}(K/E)$ and $\alpha \in E$, we have $c(\alpha) = \alpha$ so $$hch^{-1}(\alpha) = \alpha = c(\alpha).$$ Hence, $H \leq N_G(C)$.

Can you figure out the second inclusion? Probably not, because here you have $H = C$ which is not necessarily equal to $N_G(C)$.

---

For the correct result, redefine $H = \{\sigma \in G \mid \sigma(\alpha) \in E,\, \forall \alpha \in E\}$. Now, we will show $H = N_G(C)$.

Let $h \in H$, $c \in C$ and $\alpha \in E$. Then, $h^{-1}(\alpha) \in E$ because $h^{-1} \in H$. So, $ch^{-1}(\alpha) = h^{-1}(\alpha)$ because $c$ fixes $E$ and therefore, $hch^{-1}(\alpha) = hh^{-1}(\alpha) = \alpha$. Thus, $H \leq N_G(C)$.

Now, let $n \in N_G(C)$, $c \in C$ and $\alpha \in E$. Then $n^{-1} \in N_G(C)$ so, $n^{-1}cn(\alpha) = \alpha$. Applying $n$ on both sides, we get $c(n(\alpha)) = n(\alpha)$, meaning $c$ fixes $n(\alpha)$. Therefore, $n(\alpha) \in K^C = E$. Thus, $N_G(C) \leq H$. Hence, $H = N_G(C)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little be confused. Why do we choose $\alpha \in E$ but not other fields?

Comment: I simply completed your argument. You want to show that $H \leq N_G(C)$. So, you want to show that for all $h \in H$, $hCh^{-1} = C$ or in other words, for all $c \in C$, $hch^{-1} \in C$. Now, $C = \operatorname{Gal}(K/E) = \{\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K) \mid \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha,\, \forall \alpha \in E\}$. So, we only need $\alpha \in E$.

Comment: However, you may notice from this that your given group $H$ is the same as $C$ and not $N_G(C)$. I believe the correct subgroup would be $H = \{\sigma \in G \mid \sigma(\alpha) \in E,\, \forall \alpha \in E\}$ i.e. the automorphisms that map $E$ into $E$ but not necessarily fix it.

Comment: For a slightly different argument, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790144/showing-normalizer-of-galois-group/1790315#1790315

Comment: Sorry, one more question. For the last line, why do we have $n(\alpha)\in E$? Do you use the fundamental theorem of Galois corresponding theorem?

Comment: @Hermi Yes, that is the correct statement.


Recall $c \in C = \operatorname{Gal}(K/E) = \{\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K) \mid \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha, \forall \alpha \in E\}$. That is $C$ consists of all automorphisms that fix $E$. We said that $c$ fixes $n(\alpha)$ but $c \in C$ was arbitrary. Perhaps, it may be easier to understand if we write for all $c \in C$, $c(n(\alpha)) = n(\alpha)$. Hence, $n(\alpha) \in E$.


You can also use the Galois correspondence. Since $c(n(\alpha)) = n(\alpha)$ for all $c \in C$, $n(\alpha) \in K^C = E$.